# FFmpeg Two-Pass Encoding in Android

Tags: video, ffmpeg

According to the documentation for using Two-Pass method we have to run ffmpeg twice like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 2600k -pass 1 -an -f mp4 /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 2600k -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

But When I use these codes I get this error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for '&&'
```

And Android doesn't recognize `"&& \"` as an argument for ffmpeg or ffmpeg doesn't recognize such a thing on Android!

Could somebody tell me how I should do 2-Pass encoding on Android with FFmpeg?

Comment: Remove the && and execute the two commands one after another.

Comment: @Gyan if I remove && then it says "Unable to find a suitable output format for '\' " and if I remove \ it says "ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file"